# Ninject Rebind a datacontext MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, ninject, unity-container

We are using Ninject.MVC5 and Ninject.Extention.Conventions in a multi-tenant web environment with multiple databases, one for each tenant along with a primary EF database. When a user logins in, we find them in the primary database and determine what database they should work with so we can bind all our datacontexts to that DB. (We use EF for the primary database and Linq to SQL for the tenant DB).

Here is the initial bind:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
string TennantConnection= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DSN"] ?? "";
kernel.Bind<TenantDB>()
            .ToSelf()
            .InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument(typeof(string), TennantConnection);
```

Where TennantConnection is a dummy default connection string initially

Here is the Rebind that is called after the login with the updated connection string

```
kernel.Rebind<TenantDB>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument(typeof(string), ConfigConnection);
```

The kernel is injected into the constructor for the rebind class as follows:

```
public DataContextTennant(IKernel kernel)
```

All of the rest of the injections are done by convention.

The issue is that when we deploy the site (it happens to be an Azure Cloud app) many of the users get an error of an invalid SQL connection after first login which I believe is due to the rebind. But if they use a private browser session the rebind seems to work both for that session and subsequent sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that Ninject is working as expected. You should look into why the `TenantDB` is instanciated before login is complete and rebind is done. This should be what's causing your issues.

To do so, you should start with removing your default `TenantDB` binding:

```
string TennantConnection= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DSN"] ?? "";
kernel.Bind<TenantDB>()
        .ToSelf()
        .InRequestScope()
        .WithConstructorArgument(typeof(string), TennantConnection);
```

because after all, this binding only results in a `TenantDB` which is unusable, so why bother? It's just post-poning the issue to later - making it harder to detect.
It's much better to **[fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)** - have ninject throw an `ActivationException`! (which happens if there's no binding).

This should help you in finding out under which circumstances `TenantDB` is instanciated before login is complete.

---

Edit: Verification that `IBindingRoot.Rebind` works:

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void Foo()
    {
        const string text1 = "Text1";
        const string text2 = "Text2";

        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<string>().ToConstant(text1);
        kernel.Get<string>().Should().Be(text1);

        kernel.Rebind<string>().ToConstant(text2);
        kernel.Get<string>().Should().Be(text2);
    }
}
```

Ninject's rebind works. I think you're making a configuration mistake and when using ninject, your building parts of your object tree - which depend on the `DbContext` before the `Rebind` is done. Thus "pre-login `DbContext`" leaks through to after login.

If i should be mistaken, you should create a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it on Ninject's Issue tracker.

Comment: This still binds the connection - Because I am binding by convention, removing the binding just causes Ninject to bind to what Ninject determines to be a default configuration to all the repositories. Moving the bind to my rebind method does not actually do the bind, it needs to be a rebind to occur so that the original binding is cleared. Leaving it as is, I see this behavior: User1, Tennant1 login gets an error, User2, Tennant1, can login. User1 Tennant1 can login. It seems the rebind clears the original binding and replaces with the new binding but it is not used until the next request.

Comment: More detail: If I upload the site to Azure and try to login with a user, it does not use the correct datacontext, no matter how many times I try. But if I then close the browser window and reopen it with and try to login with the same user, it has the correct datacontext and allows the login.

Comment: Yeah maybe it's somehow tied to the session. It's about how/when/how many kernels you create and when you change the binding and when instances are instantiated. If there's a default binding, just replace it with `Bind<TenantDB>().ToMethod(x => throw new InvalidOperationException("the database cannot be connected to before login is completed")`. Analyse when the exception occurs.

Comment: If you want different databases per user you will need multiple conditional bindings or a `Bind<TenantDB>().ToProvider()` binding which handles the selection or multiple kernels alternatively.

Comment: I switched to unity and have been able to get a test project to work by adding in a connection string to Register Types: public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container,string connection), adding in IUnityContainer container to the home controller, then in the login view, after I get the correct connection string, calling:  UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(container,connection); This resolves everything again with the updated data context - is there something equivalent in NinJect? If not, I will try this approach with real app and report back.

Comment: Of course you can also bind `string` with ninject, even though it's not recommended (for any DI container). String is a very verbose type and it's entirely possible it's not going to take long until you run into a conflict. It's better to wrap the `string` in a class/interface like `IConnectionConfig.ConnectionString` and bind & inject that. Also, binding/registering the `connection`/`DbContext` only after successful login is what i've suggested all along.

Comment: Agreed that is the goal, it just does not seem to work in Ninject - even after binding or rebinding, all the repositories still reference the original binding and not the newly updated one, that is the essence of the issue. Since there are many repositories/services manually rebinding all of them is not an option.

Comment: See the update to my answer. Ninject's `Rebind` *does* work, so the issue must be with how you or some extension is configuring ninject for asp.net or how you build your object tree (which seems to differ from how you're doing it with unity).

Answer (score 0):

Although I was unable to resolve it with Ninject, I was able to resolve the issue with Unity. From the controller, after retrieving the tenant connection string, I call this:

```
    public static void RegisterDBTypes(IUnityContainer container, string connection)
    {
        container.RegisterType<ADataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), (new InjectionConstructor(connection)));
        container.RegisterType<RDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), (new InjectionConstructor(connection)));
        container.RegisterType<PDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), (new InjectionConstructor(connection)));
    }
```

This rebinds the data contexts which flows through to the various services and repositories.